# Test tsconfig, losing autocompletion and typing when adding paths

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig

I wanted to have separate test and src folders, I followed [this article to get this kind of setup.](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-setting-up-unit-tests-with-typescript-871c0f4f1609) Currently I am encountering the following issue. If I don't add  `paths` option to my tests/tsconfig I'll get the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module '@/models/Posts/Post'
Require stack
```

Meaning that my paths are not resolved even tho they are working in the IDE and are giving me autocompletion and typing and everything that I need. Now when I do add the path entry to the config, the tests run without any errors but in the IDE I get errors that they cannot find `@/models/Posts/Post`. Meaning that the IDE now cannot resolve the paths

This is a really bad situation as I either cannot get autocompletion and any help from the editor or I crash on tests. Not sure what to do

This is my setup

Root tsconfig used for building the actual project

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "lib": [
          "es2017",
          "esnext.asynciterable"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
          "./node_modules/@types",
          "./src/types"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "pretty": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "noEmit": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
          "@/*": ["./src/*"]
        }
      },
      "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "tests"
      ]
}
```

And this is the tsconfig inside my tests directory

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["../src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["../node_modules", "*.js"],
  "include": ["./**/*.ts", "../src/**/*"]
}
```

Project structure is

root 
| - src (ts files) 
| - dist (compiled js)  
| - tests

As the article mentions I use regsiter.js

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const tsNode = require("ts-node");
const tsConfigPaths = require("tsconfig-paths");
const mainTSConfig = require("./tsconfig.json");
const testTSConfig = require("./tests/tsconfig.json");

tsConfigPaths.register({
  baseUrl: "./tests",
  paths: {
    ...mainTSConfig.compilerOptions.paths,
    ...testTSConfig.compilerOptions.paths,
  },
});

tsNode.register({
  files: true,
  transpileOnly: true,
  project: "./tests/tsconfig.json",
});
```

With .mocharc.json

```
{
    "require": "./register.js",
    "reporter": "dot"
}
```

And running my tests with
`"test": "nyc ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha 'tests/**/*.test.ts'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer:

Add `"baseUrl": "."` to your `tests/tsconfig.json`.

### Explanation:

The `tests/tsconfig.json` inherits the `baseUrl` from the main `tsconfig.json` file (but still resolves it relative to that file).
This means that the `baseUrl` in `tests/tsconfig.json` is effectively `".."`.
Tip: You can use the TypeScript compiler to show all inherited and otherwis derived values of your tsconfig file: `tsc -p tests/tsconfig.json --showConfig`
The `paths` are resolved relative to the `baseUrl`.
And since you specify the `baseUrl` explicitly in `register.js`, you need to make sure that the different `baseUrl`s point to the same directory (here `tests`) so the paths can consistently be resolved by both IDE and `tsconfig-paths` at runtime.